# How to uninstall DirectX11 and install directx10 on windows 7

Tags: window, directx, video-capture

I am trying to capture a video with a Star-tech capture card using OBS(Open Broadcast Software) non windows 7. The problem I am facing is that OBS requires Directx10 for working and windows 7 by default comes with Directx11 which is messing up the capturing. However I have tried uninstalling DirectX11 from registry except the default key there. The weird thing is that even after I have deleted it from registry it still shows Directx11 installed (checked using dxdiag). Moreover i have surfed the internet like anything and I have not been able to find a working  link to download Directx 10. I have been stuck on this for a while now. Any suggestions to help me uninstall Directx11 and download and install Directx 10 on windows 7 will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 supports DirectX 9.0c except for [DirectPlay Voice](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/970978) and [Direct3D Retained Mode](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969150). It also supports DirectX 10.0, DirectX 10.1, and DirectX 11.0. It has partial support for DirectX 11.1 with [KB2670838](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) installed.

You cannot 'uninstall' the DirectX 11 runtime from Windows 7 any more than you can 'uninstall' the Windows UI or the file system. The only thing "DirectX" you can 'install' on Windows 7 is the various legacy DirectX SDK optional bits (D3DX9, D3DX10, D3DX11, XACT, debug layer, etc.) and the DirectX 11.1 Runtime via KB2670838.

See [Direct3D 11 Deployment for Game Developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx) and [Not So Direct Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup.aspx) as well as [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx).

If your application isn't working, that's an appcompat bug with the software. You can try various Compatibility Modes when running it to see if that works.